# How to push values to new array by comparing 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays.

```
selectedgroup = [ ID:1, selected:true,
                  ID:2, selected:false,
                  ..... ]
```

The 2nd array is,

```
 mainarr=[ ID:1, mainid:25, name:ser, pID:545,
            ID:2, mainid:84, name:ferdi, pID:678,
            ID:3, mainid:88, name:ferSER, pID:656,
              ....]
```

I want to check if `mainarr` contains an element of `selectedgroup`. The unique id in both arrays is **ID** . Then I want to push it on a new array. 
How can I do this?

Comment: The syntax here doesn't look valid. If these are arrays of objects, I recommend formatting them as such to eliminate any confusion about what we're working with. Beyond that, I recommend sharing your attempt as a [mcve] and showing your exact expected output given these two structures you've shown. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array is in following valid format. Iterate over your `mainarr` and check if `ID` of `mainarr` matches the `ID` of `selectedgroup` array then simply push the object into new array. Like following:

```js
var selectedgroup = [ {ID:1, selected:true},{ID:2, selected:false} ];
var mainarr = [ {ID:1, mainid:25, name:'ser', pID:545},{ID:2, mainid:84, name:'ferdi', pID:678},{ID:3, mainid:88, name:'ferSER', pID:656}];
var newArray = [];
mainarr.forEach(function(mainObject) {
   for (let i=0; i<selectedgroup.length; i++){
        if(selectedgroup [i].ID === mainObject.ID){
           newArray.push(mainObject);
        }
   }
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
var newarr =[];
for(i=0; i<mainarr.length; i++){
 for(j=0;j<selectedgroup.length; j++){
  if(mainarr[i].ID = selectedgroup[j].ID)
  {
  newarr.push(mainarr[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think use of filter, is a better method than use of forEach. So I just include this solution for reference.

```js
var selectedgroup = [ {ID:1, selected:true},{ID:2, selected:false} ];
var mainarr = [ {ID:1, mainid:25, name:'ser', pID:545},{ID:2, mainid:84, name:'ferdi', pID:678},{ID:3, mainid:88, name:'ferSER', pID:656}];


const selectedgroupIds = selectedgroup.map(selected => selected.ID);

const newarr =  mainarr.filter(main => {
  return selectedgroupIds.indexOf(main.ID) !== -1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. Like following:

```
var selectedgroup = [ {ID:1, selected:true},{ID:2, selected:false} ];
var mainarr = [ {ID:1, mainid:25, name:'ser', pID:545},{ID:2, mainid:84, name:'ferdi', pID:678},{ID:3, mainid:88, name:'ferSER', pID:656}];
var newarr = mainarr.filter(function(eachArr){
              for (var i = 0; i < selectedgroup.length; i++){
                 if(selectedgroup [i].ID === eachArr.ID){
                   return true;
                 } }})
```

If selectedgroup array can have many values, you can use map to get all ids first to avoid inner loop and then filter with them as @CHANist said.

For your reference: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
Thus, the code would become

```
var selectedgroup = [ {ID:1, selected:true},{ID:2, selected:false} ];
var mainarr = [ {ID:1, mainid:25, name:'ser', pID:545},{ID:2, mainid:84, name:'ferdi', pID:678},{ID:3, mainid:88, name:'ferSER', pID:656}];
var ids = selectedgroup.map(function(obj){ return obj.ID});
var newarr = mainarr.filter(function(eachArr){
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedgroup.length; i++){
                   if(ids.indexOf(eachArr.ID) !== -1){
                      return true;
                    } }})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code,**

```
var selectedgroup = [
                      {ID:1, selected:true},
                      {ID:2, selected:false}
                  ];
var mainarr = [
                  {ID:1, mainid:25, name:'ser', pID:545},
                  {ID:2, mainid:84, name:'ferdi', pID:678},
                  {ID:3, mainid:88, name:'ferSER', pID:656}
              ];
var newArray=[];
for (var i = 0, l2 = mainarr .length; i < l2; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, l1 = selectedgroup .length; j < l1; j++) {
        if(mainarr [i].ID===selectedgroup [j].ID){
            newArray.push(mainarr [i]);
        }
    }
 }
 console.log(newArray);
```